# How can I adjust detecting latency in ML kit text recognition?

Tags: google-mlkit

I want to lower the latency of detection because I get too many words in a second. I've tried to lower it by changing variables like FPS, maxFrameMs, minFramems, etc(almost everything regarding to latency) in VisonProcessorBase.java and InferenceInfoGraphic.java class but it didn't work.
How can I lower the speed of detection?

Answer (score 0):

Those variables are just used for counting rather configuring camera.

You can play with [REQUESTED_FPS](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/CameraSource.java#L83) constant and [#selectPreviewFpsRange](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/CameraSource.java#L452) method inside the CameraSource.java class to lower the speed of frame feeding for detection.